# How to load different js files on different views

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

I have single page app with 5 different views and i don't know where to start when it comes to loading js files on other views. I have separate js files for every view and 1 main file. I put script tag in view but I know that's not good solution. Here is my main js file that goes through navigation and updates views.

```
        // Wrap everything in an immediately invoked function expression,
        // so no global variables are introduced.
        (function () {

          // Stores the cached partial HTML pages.
          // Keys correspond to fragment identifiers.
          // Values are the text content of each loaded partial HTML file.
          var partialsCache = {}

          // Gets the appropriate content for the given fragment identifier.
          // This function implements a simple cache.
          function getContent(fragmentId, callback){

            // If the page has been fetched before,
            if(partialsCache[fragmentId]) {

              // pass the previously fetched content to the callback.
              callback(partialsCache[fragmentId]);

            } else {
              // If the page has not been fetched before, fetch it.
              $.get("views/" + fragmentId + ".php", function (content) {

                // Store the fetched content in the cache.
                partialsCache[fragmentId] = content;

                // Pass the newly fetched content to the callback.
                callback(content);
              });
            }
          }

          // Sets the "active" class on the active navigation link.
          function setActiveLink(fragmentId){
            $("#navbar a").each(function (i, linkElement) {
              var link = $(linkElement),
                  pageName = link.attr("href").substr(1);
              if(pageName === fragmentId) {
                link.addClass("active");
              } else {
                link.removeClass("active");
              }
            });
          }

          // Updates dynamic content based on the fragment identifier.
          function navigate(){

            // Isolate the fragment identifier using substr.
            // This gets rid of the "#" character.
            var fragmentId = location.hash.substr(1);

            // Set the "content" div innerHTML based on the fragment identifier.
            getContent(fragmentId, function (content) {
              $("#content").html(content);
            });


            // Toggle the "active" class on the link currently navigated to.
            setActiveLink(fragmentId);
          }

          // If no fragment identifier is provided,
          if(!location.hash) {

            // default to #home.
            location.hash = "#home";
          }

          // Navigate once to the initial fragment identifier.
          navigate();

          // Navigate whenever the fragment identifier value changes.
          $(window).bind('hashchange', navigate);
        }());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadJS(file) {
    // DOM: Create the script element
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    // set the type attribute
    jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
    // make the script element load file
    jsElm.src = file;
    // finally insert the element to the body element in order to load the script
    document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
}
```

use this function for multiple js files or you can also convert the parameter of a function to an array of strings which will be array of js files location and accordingly change logic in the function to load multiple scripts

Comment: yea but when u click through menus it appends script over an over again and I ended up with dozens of script tags with same src until I refresh page